# children selector in css

Tags: css

I have a nested html like this:

```
<div id="feautred">
  <div></div>
  <p></p>
  <ul></ul>
  <dl></dl>
</div>
```

For normal markup I could use `#featured > div` but here is not only the div is nested. There may be anything. So, how can I use `#featured > ????` selector here?

---

Doing `#featured > *` will select all inner children what I don't need! I want only main children elements to be selected.

Comment: `#features > *` will not select all descendant elements, it will only select direct children of `#featured`. The style you apply to these children may be inherited by elements which are deeper in DOM, but that's because of how CSS inheritance works, not because this selector selects these elements.

Comment: Do you mean children, or descendants? What do you mean by “main children elements”?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks I was mistakenly thought that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `*`:

```
#features > *
```

from [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors):

> The universal selector, written as a CSS qualified name
>   [CSS3NAMESPACE] with an asterisk (`*` U+002A) as the local name,
>   **represents the qualified name of any element type**.

Comment: I believe C-link only wants the direct children and not inner children.

Comment: Ah, your comment above regarding CSS inheritance cleared it up my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
#featured + p { }
```

This will select all paragraphs that are following #featured.